# Prevent cloud-init from creating disk partitions

Tags: azure, cloud-init

I am setting up a VM in azure and it comes with an ephemeral(ssd) disk. This disk is on /dev/sdb and cloud init is creating a partition /dev/sdb1 on it. I am using centos7 with cloud init 19.4.
Using the config below.
I was wondering if there was any way I cloud do this without creating a partition?

```
datasource_list: [ Azure ]
device_aliases: {'ephemeral0': '/dev/sdb'}
disk_setup:
    ephemeral0:
         table_type: 'gpt'
         layout: 'true'
         overwrite: 'false'

fs_setup:
    - label: ephemeral0
      filesystem: xfs
      device: ephemeral0.0

mounts:
  - ["ephemeral0", "/logs"]
```

```
sdb           8:16   0  160G  0 disk
`-sdb1        8:17   0  160G  0 part /logs
```

I went through the docs and I've tried setting layout to false as well but it does not seem to work. The logs always say this and I can't seem to figure out where this is coming from.

```
"manual request of partition 1 for /dev/sdb1"
```

Answer (score 0):

`disk_setup` is what is creating the partition. You can create the filesystem on the partition-less disk like this:

```
#cloud-config
fs_setup:
    - label: ephemeral0
      filesystem: xfs
      device: /dev/sdb

mounts:
  - ["/dev/sdb", "/logs"]
```

Comment: I tried using this but a partition is still being created albeit with a different mount point this time.


sdb       8:16   0  160G  0 disk
`-sdb1    8:17   0  160G  0 part /mnt